# $('#id').toggle() is changing style="display:none" to style="" instead of the desired style="display:inline"

Tags: jquery, css

I have:

```
<a id = "button" style="display:inline"></a>
<a id = "buttonPressed" style="display:none"></a>
```

And I'm using

```
$('#button, #buttonPressed').click(function(event) {
    $('#button, #buttonPressed').toggle();
    //Do other stuff
})
```

The "display:inline" button is getting changed to "display:none" as desired, but the "display:none" button is changing to style="" instead of the desired "display:inline".

How do I address this?

Comment: Cannot replicate this issue. Please declare what browser you're using that is causing this issue.

Comment: This is with the latest Chrome (20.0.1132.57) / Windows 7

Comment: Why does this matter? it will be `inline` implicitly because it's `a` element

Comment: It matters because it's not displaying right.. the button with style="" is appearing larger than the others in the set, and when I open the Chrome dev tool and manually change it to style="display:inline" it looks right again

Comment: Thanks all for the fast responses! The jsfiddles people posted are working properly for me too. I will try the suggestions here and also check for possible conflicting code I might have missed and then report back

Comment: @JoeM. if manually writing `display="inline"` fixes your bug then it has to do with forcing a rerender or something. But `a` elements are by default `inline` and there is no need to specify it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try `toggleClass()`:

```
.hidden {
   display: none
}
```

```
<a id="button">click1</a>
<a id="buttonPressed" class="hidden">click2</a>
```

```
$('#button, #buttonPressed').click(function(event) {
    $('#button, #buttonPressed').toggleClass('hidden');
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bR2aG/)

Comment: I still haven't figured out the root of the problem but this was successful as a workaround for the time being. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to those tags.  Create a css rule that enforces the inline display in the rule.

Comment: [I can't imagine why he'd need to do that when the state's are toggling properly.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/bmLPM/)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmase05/DjHNb/)

So maybe there is some other conflicting code on your page?